# Crazy Wifi Connection

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom, 15.04

I've just bought a DELL XPS 13". Testing the new Ubuntu 15.04, everything was ok. During the test I've just enabled an additional driver for the Wi-fi (Broadcom bcm4352 ).

So I've installed Ubuntu.

After, enabled again the additional driver, the Wi-fi didn't work well. It was possible to connect to any connections, but not to navigate. I though it was a driver problem. So I used a usb wifi key (already used in different ubuntu versions) and still have the same problem.

The problem is that I can navigate on internet for some seconds, then not. Internet goes in intermittent. I've already checked that there's no problem with the router or thing like this.

How do I proceed?

P.S. I never lost the connection with the router.

Comment: How do you connect to Internet ? Network Manager ? Is there anything in the log ? Look at dmesg output or /var/log/syslog file.